# Compute optimal route with cost penalty for vertex stop

Tags: r, optimization, igraph

I am looking to compute optimal travel routes with R. Imagine I have a travel time table like the following one.

With igraph and distance_table, my colleague and I have figured out how to compute travel routes that minimize the sum of travel time, or that minimize the number of edges in the route (which I do by setting all travel times to 1).

What I have not figured out how to do, is to compute minimal travel times but add a time travel penalty for each stopping point. That way, I would avoid getting optimal routes with too many stopovers. What is the best way to do this? I want to do it with R, but I am open to using libraries other than igraph (that I am not that familiar with).

| Origin | Destination | Travel Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| A | C | 20 |
| A | D | 10 |
| A | E | 30 |
| B | A | 10 |
| B | D | 5 |
| C | A | 20 |
| D | A | 10 |
| D | B | 5 |
| E | A | 30 |

Comment: `"I have figured out how to compute travel routes that minimize the sum of travel time..."` Please share the code so we can start somewhere and not reinvent your codes.

Comment: Why not just add the stopover penalty to each travel time?

Comment: how the "cost penalty" looks like? please show an example in your question

Comment: @jblood94: of course!!! the answer was right in front of my nose. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use `igraph` here to make your job easier.

First, convert your data frame to a graph object, which is as easy as:

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

We can see what this looks like by doing

```r
plot(g)
```

[image]

If we want the shortest distance between nodes, taking travelling time into account, we can simply use the function `distances`, using the travel times as weights:

```r
travel_times <- edge_attr(g, 'Travel Time')

times <- distances(g, weights = travel_times)
times
#>    A  B  C  D  E
#> A  0 10 20 10 30
#> B 10  0 30  5 40
#> C 20 30  0 30 50
#> D 10  5 30  0 40
#> E 30 40 50 40  0
```

If we want to add a fixed stopover time, then we can add a fixed weight to each edge. We need to remove a single stopover time at the end for all non-zero entries in our distance matrix, since there will be n-1 stopovers if n edges are traversed:

```r
stopover_time <- 5
times_with_stopover <- travel_times + stopover_time

totals <- distances(g, weights = times_with_stopover)

totals[totals > 0] <- totals[totals > 0] - stopover_time
totals
#>    A  B  C  D  E
#> A  0 10 20 10 30
#> B 10  0 35  5 45
#> C 20 35  0 35 55
#> D 10  5 35  0 45
#> E 30 45 55 45  0
```

If the stopover times vary according to the node, then this information could be encoded according to the destination node in the input data frame.

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data frame from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Origin = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"D", "D", "E"), Destination = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "D", 
"A", "A", "B", "A"), `Travel Time` = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 30L, 10L, 
5L, 20L, 10L, 5L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: This is close, but you are computing `n_nodes` from an unweighted graph so the shortest paths may differ from those on which `times` is based.

Comment: @RobertHacken yes, you're right. I think if the stopover penalty is the same at each node, then adding a fixed penalty for each edge in the distance weighting should work.

Comment: @RobertHacken yes, that seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it does! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach which would allow for different stopping times at different points.

The main idea is to divide each vertex into two, *in* and *out*. All edges leading to the original point will lead to the *in* vertex and all edges leaving it will start at the *out* vertex. The two will be connected by a single edge from *in* to *out* with its weight representing the stopping time.

```r
# vertex names
v <- unique(unlist(df[, c('Origin', 'Destination')]))
# change vertex names to e.g. 'A.in' and 'A.out'
df$Origin <- paste0(df$Origin, '.out')
df$Destination <- paste0(df$Destination, '.in')
# add stopping penalties
df <- rbind(df, list(paste0(v, '.in'), paste0(v, '.out'), rep(5, length(v))))
```

So now `df` looks like this:

```r
#    Origin Destination Travel Time
# 1   A.out        B.in          10
# 2   A.out        C.in          20
# 3   A.out        D.in          10
# 4   A.out        E.in          30
# 5   B.out        A.in          10
# 6   B.out        D.in           5
# 7   C.out        A.in          20
# 8   D.out        A.in          10
# 9   D.out        B.in           5
# 10  E.out        A.in          30
# 11   A.in       A.out           5
# 21   B.in       B.out           5
# 31   C.in       C.out           5
# 41   D.in       D.out           5
# 51   E.in       E.out           5
```

And the shortest paths can be computed:

```r
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value=df$`Travel Time`)

# compute only distances from "out" to "in" vertices
d <- distances(g, mode='out', v=paste0(v, '.out'), to=paste0(v, '.in'))
diag(d) <- 0
rownames(d) <- colnames(d) <- v
d
#    A  B  C  D  E
# A  0 10 20 10 30
# B 10  0 35  5 45
# C 20 35  0 35 55
# D 10  5 35  0 45
# E 30 45 55 45  0
```

Data from @Allan Cameron's answer:

```r
df <- structure(list(Origin = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"D", "D", "E"), Destination = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "D", 
"A", "A", "B", "A"), `Travel Time` = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 30L, 10L, 
5L, 20L, 10L, 5L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Very clever Robert!